# Macbook air Wifi won't start on boot anymore. arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, macbook-air

I rebooted my computer manually this morning, via the power button on the keyboard, because I have yet to find out how to get my macbook to sleep correctly. When it booted back up it failed to start my Network Manager. I ran Ip a an found that my wifi card is denied.

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09) DeviceName: SATA Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device 011b Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0 Capabilities:

I don't why it's denied. It all happened as soon as I reboot my computer this morning. Any ideas on how to fix??

Comment: why was this down voted?

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted but its probably because your question is not very clear. Please refer to [how to ask a good question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) & edit your post